# Modify xls to look for any existing attribute, if present don't overwrite w/ xsi:nil="true"

Tags: xslt

I have the following problem. I have an xls stylesheet to add the xsi:nil="true" null attribute to blank nodes in my xml data. However if a node already has an attribute `<test s:id"121"/>` the xls is deleting it and overwriting w/ `<test xsi:nil="true"/>` thinking it's blank. I don't want this behavior, I only want the xsi:nil="true" added if the node is truly blank `<test/>` w/ no attribute. Can someone help me modify the following xls stylesheet w/ the proper conditional statement to skip over nodes like this `<test s:id"121"/>` that have an attribute present? The attribute may vary, I just need to ignore the null attribute insert if any type of attribute already exists.

Would it also be possible to change the xsl below to also look for blank nodes like this `<test></test>` and turn it into `<test xsi:nil="true"\>` this. Right now it only works to add the null attribute if it's in this format `<test/>` It would be nice to work both ways. Tnx.

XLS example that overwrites existing node attributes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"`
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(text())]">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a check for attributes in your template match too...

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(text()) and not(@*)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You might want to be precise as to your definition of empty. For example, with this current template match, the `a` element would be considered empty in the following XML, as `a` has no child text nodes or attributes.

```
<a><b>Hello</b></a>
```

So, perhaps the template match should be like this....?

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(text()) and not(*) and not(@*)]">
```

Comment: Tim, thank you so much! That worked great. 

How hard would be to modify this xls template to look for blank elements like this `<a></a>` and also `<a/>` and always convert them to `<a xsi:nil="true"\>` Right now, the xsl above only supports finding blank elements like this `<a/>` so I have run my xml payload through XmlUtil.serialize() method to convert all blank elements to `<a/>` this style then apply the xls transformation. Would like to eliminate the extra serialize step and do it all in the stylesheet. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The above template should match `<a></a>`. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kr. Are you sure it hasn't got some whitespace in there. Try changing the template match to `<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space()) and not(@*)]">`

Comment: Thanks, whatever it was, this resolved it. Thanks so much your help!